# Wallet Connect / Web3 Provider showing a lot of errors just by imoprting

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, web3js

I want to use "@walletconnect/web3-provider" JS library in my project, but once I installed the library along with Web3 module (they will be used together)

```
npm install --save web3 @walletconnect/web3-provider
```

and after that import it into my project (in App.js file in a React project)

```
import WalletConnectProvider from '@walletconnect/web3-provider';
```

it complains of so many errors!

```
19 errors have detailed information that is not shown.
Use 'stats.errorDetails: true' resp. '--stats-error-details' to show it.

webpack 5.68.0 compiled with 19 errors and 110 warnings in 23859 ms
```

Here is the part of the error message as it appears in the server side (in vs code terminal):

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/@walletconnect/jsonrpc-types/dist/esm/index.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\@walletconnect\jsonrpc-types\src\index.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\@walletconnect\jsonrpc-types\src\index.ts'        
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/jsonrpc-utils/dist/esm/types.js 1:0-45 1:0-45
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/jsonrpc-utils/dist/esm/index.js 6:0-24 6:0-24
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/utils/dist/esm/misc.js 2:0-61 16:25-47
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/utils/dist/esm/index.js 5:0-23 5:0-23
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/web3-provider/dist/esm/index.js 4:0-95 61:19-36 68:12-21 73:25-42 190:9-32 326:23-32 347:12-21
 @ ./src/App.js 7:0-65 18:24-45
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 11:33-36

WARNING in ./node_modules/@walletconnect/jsonrpc-types/dist/esm/jsonrpc.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\@walletconnect\jsonrpc-types\src\jsonrpc.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\@walletconnect\jsonrpc-types\src\jsonrpc.ts'    
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/jsonrpc-types/dist/esm/index.js 1:0-26 1:0-26
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/jsonrpc-utils/dist/esm/types.js 1:0-45 1:0-45
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/jsonrpc-utils/dist/esm/index.js 6:0-24 6:0-24
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/utils/dist/esm/misc.js 2:0-61 16:25-47
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/utils/dist/esm/index.js 5:0-23 5:0-23
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/web3-provider/dist/esm/index.js 4:0-95 61:19-36 68:12-21 73:25-42 190:9-32 326:23-32 347:12-21
 @ ./src/App.js 7:0-65 18:24-45
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 11:33-36

WARNING in ./node_modules/@walletconnect/jsonrpc-types/dist/esm/misc.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\@walletconnect\jsonrpc-types\src\misc.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\@walletconnect\jsonrpc-types\src\misc.ts'
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/jsonrpc-types/dist/esm/index.js 2:0-23 2:0-23
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/jsonrpc-utils/dist/esm/types.js 1:0-45 1:0-45
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/jsonrpc-utils/dist/esm/index.js 6:0-24 6:0-24
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/utils/dist/esm/misc.js 2:0-61 16:25-47
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/utils/dist/esm/index.js 5:0-23 5:0-23
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/web3-provider/dist/esm/index.js 4:0-95 61:19-36 68:12-21 73:25-42 190:9-32 326:23-32 347:12-21
 @ ./src/App.js 7:0-65 18:24-45
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 11:33-36

WARNING in ./node_modules/@walletconnect/jsonrpc-utils/dist/esm/url.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\@walletconnect\jsonrpc-utils\src\url.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\@walletconnect\jsonrpc-utils\src\url.ts'
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/jsonrpc-utils/dist/esm/index.js 7:0-22 7:0-22
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/utils/dist/esm/misc.js 2:0-61 16:25-47
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/utils/dist/esm/index.js 5:0-23 5:0-23
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/web3-provider/dist/esm/index.js 4:0-95 61:19-36 68:12-21 73:25-42 190:9-32 326:23-32 347:12-21
 @ ./src/App.js 7:0-65 18:24-45
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 11:33-36

WARNING in ./node_modules/@walletconnect/jsonrpc-utils/dist/esm/validators.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\@walletconnect\jsonrpc-utils\src\validators.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\@walletconnect\jsonrpc-utils\src\validators.ts'
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/jsonrpc-utils/dist/esm/index.js 8:0-29 8:0-29
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/utils/dist/esm/misc.js 2:0-61 16:25-47
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/utils/dist/esm/index.js 5:0-23 5:0-23
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/web3-provider/dist/esm/index.js 4:0-95 61:19-36 68:12-21 73:25-42 190:9-32 326:23-32 347:12-21
 @ ./src/App.js 7:0-65 18:24-45
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 11:33-36

WARNING in ./node_modules/@walletconnect/randombytes/dist/esm/browser/index.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\@walletconnect\randombytes\src\browser\index.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\@walletconnect\randombytes\src\browser\index.ts'
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/crypto/dist/esm/browser/index.js 1:0-43 1:0-43
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/iso-crypto/dist/esm/index.js 1:0-48 7:16-34 17:22-43 34:27-47 37:21-42 60:23-43
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/client/dist/esm/index.js 2:0-55 7:6-15
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/web3-provider/dist/esm/index.js 1:0-50 98:36-49
 @ ./src/App.js 7:0-65 18:24-45
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 11:33-36

WARNING in ./node_modules/@walletconnect/safe-json/dist/esm/index.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\@walletconnect\safe-json\src\index.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\@walletconnect\safe-json\src\index.ts'
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/browser-utils/dist/esm/json.js 1:0-53 2:29-51 3:33-59
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/browser-utils/dist/esm/index.js 2:0-23 2:0-23
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/qrcode-modal/dist/cjs/index.js 5:19-58
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/web3-provider/dist/esm/index.js 2:0-54 27:23-34
 @ ./src/App.js 7:0-65 18:24-45
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 11:33-36

WARNING in ./node_modules/@walletconnect/socket-transport/dist/esm/index.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\@walletconnect\socket-transport\src\index.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\@walletconnect\socket-transport\src\index.ts'  
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/core/dist/esm/index.js 2:0-62 55:44-59
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/client/dist/esm/index.js 1:0-44 4:28-37
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/web3-provider/dist/esm/index.js 1:0-50 98:36-49
 @ ./src/App.js 7:0-65 18:24-45
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 11:33-36

WARNING in ./node_modules/@walletconnect/socket-transport/dist/esm/network.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\@walletconnect\socket-transport\src\network.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\@walletconnect\socket-transport\src\network.ts'
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/socket-transport/dist/esm/index.js 2:0-39 18:46-60
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/core/dist/esm/index.js 2:0-62 55:44-59
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/client/dist/esm/index.js 1:0-44 4:28-37
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/web3-provider/dist/esm/index.js 1:0-50 98:36-49
 @ ./src/App.js 7:0-65 18:24-45
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 11:33-36

WARNING in ./node_modules/@walletconnect/utils/dist/esm/constants.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\@walletconnect\utils\src\constants.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\@walletconnect\utils\src\constants.ts'
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/utils/dist/esm/index.js 2:0-28 2:0-28
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/web3-provider/dist/esm/index.js 4:0-95 61:19-36 68:12-21 73:25-42 190:9-32 326:23-32 347:12-21
 @ ./src/App.js 7:0-65 18:24-45
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 11:33-36

WARNING in ./node_modules/@walletconnect/utils/dist/esm/encoding.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\@walletconnect\utils\src\encoding.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\@walletconnect\utils\src\encoding.ts'
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/utils/dist/esm/index.js 3:0-27 3:0-27
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/web3-provider/dist/esm/index.js 4:0-95 61:19-36 68:12-21 73:25-42 190:9-32 326:23-32 347:12-21
 @ ./src/App.js 7:0-65 18:24-45
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 11:33-36

WARNING in ./node_modules/@walletconnect/utils/dist/esm/url.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\@walletconnect\utils\src\url.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no 
such file or directory, open 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\@walletconnect\utils\src\url.ts'
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/utils/dist/esm/index.js 8:0-22 8:0-22
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/web3-provider/dist/esm/index.js 4:0-95 61:19-36 68:12-21 73:25-42 190:9-32 326:23-32 347:12-21
 @ ./src/App.js 7:0-65 18:24-45
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 11:33-36

WARNING in ./node_modules/@walletconnect/utils/dist/esm/validators.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\@walletconnect\utils\src\validators.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\@walletconnect\utils\src\validators.ts'
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/utils/dist/esm/index.js 9:0-29 9:0-29
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/web3-provider/dist/esm/index.js 4:0-95 61:19-36 68:12-21 73:25-42 190:9-32 326:23-32 347:12-21
 @ ./src/App.js 7:0-65 18:24-45
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 11:33-36

WARNING in ./node_modules/@walletconnect/web3-provider/dist/esm/index.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\@walletconnect\web3-provider\src\index.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\@walletconnect\web3-provider\src\index.ts'        
 @ ./src/App.js 7:0-65 18:24-45
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 11:33-36

WARNING in ./node_modules/@walletconnect/window-getters/dist/cjs/index.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\@walletconnect\window-getters\src\index.ts' file: Error: 
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\@walletconnect\window-getters\src\index.ts'
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/browser-utils/dist/esm/browser.js 2:0-63 32:29-56 33:36-70 34:34-66 35:27-52 36:35-68 37:28-54 38:34-66 39:27-52 40:32-62 41:25-48 42:38-74 43:31-60
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/browser-utils/dist/esm/index.js 1:0-26 1:0-26
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/qrcode-modal/dist/cjs/index.js 5:19-58
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/web3-provider/dist/esm/index.js 2:0-54 27:23-34
 @ ./src/App.js 7:0-65 18:24-45
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 11:33-36

WARNING in ./node_modules/@walletconnect/window-metadata/dist/cjs/index.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\@walletconnect\window-metadata\src\index.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\@walletconnect\window-metadata\src\index.ts'    
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/browser-utils/dist/esm/browser.js 1:0-65 45:9-41
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/browser-utils/dist/esm/index.js 1:0-26 1:0-26
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/qrcode-modal/dist/cjs/index.js 5:19-58
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/web3-provider/dist/esm/index.js 2:0-54 27:23-34
 @ ./src/App.js 7:0-65 18:24-45
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 11:33-36

WARNING in ./node_modules/ethereumjs-abi/node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist/account.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\ethereumjs-abi\node_modules\ethereumjs-util\src\account.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\ethereumjs-abi\node_modules\ethereumjs-util\src\account.ts'
 @ ./node_modules/ethereumjs-abi/node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist/index.js 49:13-33
 @ ./node_modules/ethereumjs-abi/lib/index.js 2:14-40
 @ ./node_modules/ethereumjs-abi/index.js 1:0-42
 @ ./node_modules/eth-sig-util/index.js 3:15-40
 @ ./node_modules/web3-provider-engine/subproviders/hooked-wallet.js 16:16-39
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/web3-provider/dist/esm/index.js 14:32-90
 @ ./src/App.js 7:0-65 18:24-45
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 11:33-36

WARNING in ./node_modules/ethereumjs-abi/node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist/bytes.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\ethereumjs-abi\node_modules\ethereumjs-util\src\bytes.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\ethereumjs-abi\node_modules\ethereumjs-util\src\bytes.ts'
 @ ./node_modules/ethereumjs-abi/node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist/index.js 67:13-31
 @ ./node_modules/ethereumjs-abi/lib/index.js 2:14-40
 @ ./node_modules/ethereumjs-abi/index.js 1:0-42
 @ ./node_modules/eth-sig-util/index.js 3:15-40
 @ ./node_modules/web3-provider-engine/subproviders/hooked-wallet.js 16:16-39
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/web3-provider/dist/esm/index.js 14:32-90
 @ ./src/App.js 7:0-65 18:24-45
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 11:33-36

WARNING in ./node_modules/ethereumjs-abi/node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist/constants.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\ethereumjs-abi\node_modules\ethereumjs-util\src\constants.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\ethereumjs-abi\node_modules\ethereumjs-util\src\constants.ts'
 @ ./node_modules/ethereumjs-abi/node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist/index.js 43:13-35
 @ ./node_modules/ethereumjs-abi/lib/index.js 2:14-40
 @ ./node_modules/ethereumjs-abi/index.js 1:0-42
 @ ./node_modules/eth-sig-util/index.js 3:15-40
 @ ./node_modules/web3-provider-engine/subproviders/hooked-wallet.js 16:16-39
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/web3-provider/dist/esm/index.js 14:32-90
 @ ./src/App.js 7:0-65 18:24-45
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 11:33-36

WARNING in ./node_modules/ethereumjs-abi/node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist/hash.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\ethereumjs-abi\node_modules\ethereumjs-util\src\hash.ts' 
file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\ethereumjs-abi\node_modules\ethereumjs-util\src\hash.ts'
 @ ./node_modules/ethereumjs-abi/node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist/index.js 55:13-30
 @ ./node_modules/ethereumjs-abi/lib/index.js 2:14-40
 @ ./node_modules/ethereumjs-abi/index.js 1:0-42
 @ ./node_modules/eth-sig-util/index.js 3:15-40
 @ ./node_modules/web3-provider-engine/subproviders/hooked-wallet.js 16:16-39
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/web3-provider/dist/esm/index.js 14:32-90
 @ ./src/App.js 7:0-65 18:24-45
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 11:33-36

WARNING in ./node_modules/ethereumjs-abi/node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist/index.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\ethereumjs-abi\node_modules\ethereumjs-util\src\index.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\ethereumjs-abi\node_modules\ethereumjs-util\src\index.ts'
 @ ./node_modules/ethereumjs-abi/lib/index.js 2:14-40
 @ ./node_modules/ethereumjs-abi/index.js 1:0-42
 @ ./node_modules/eth-sig-util/index.js 3:15-40
 @ ./node_modules/web3-provider-engine/subproviders/hooked-wallet.js 16:16-39
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/web3-provider/dist/esm/index.js 14:32-90
 @ ./src/App.js 7:0-65 18:24-45
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 11:33-36


WARNING in ./node_modules/json-rpc-engine/dist/getUniqueId.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\json-rpc-engine\src\getUniqueId.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: 
no such file or directory, open 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\json-rpc-engine\src\getUniqueId.ts'
 @ ./node_modules/json-rpc-engine/dist/index.js 30:13-37
 @ ./node_modules/eth-json-rpc-filters/subscriptionManager.js 7:4-30
 @ ./node_modules/web3-provider-engine/subproviders/subscriptions.js 3:34-85
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/web3-provider/dist/esm/index.js 18:33-91
 @ ./src/App.js 7:0-65 18:24-45
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 11:33-36

WARNING in ./node_modules/json-rpc-engine/node_modules/eth-rpc-errors/dist/index.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\json-rpc-engine\node_modules\eth-rpc-errors\src\index.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\json-rpc-engine\node_modules\eth-rpc-errors\src\index.ts'
 @ ./node_modules/json-rpc-engine/dist/JsonRpcEngine.js 16:25-50
 @ ./node_modules/json-rpc-engine/dist/index.js 32:13-39
 @ ./node_modules/eth-json-rpc-filters/subscriptionManager.js 7:4-30
 @ ./node_modules/web3-provider-engine/subproviders/subscriptions.js 3:34-85
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/web3-provider/dist/esm/index.js 18:33-91
 @ ./src/App.js 7:0-65 18:24-45
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 11:33-36



WARNING in ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/index.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\index.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file 
or directory, open 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\index.ts'
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/http-connection/dist/esm/index.js 2:0-46 4:47-61
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/web3-provider/dist/esm/index.js 3:0-60 338:22-36
 @ ./src/App.js 7:0-65 18:24-45
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 11:33-36


WARNING in ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request-upload.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\xml-http-request-upload.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\xml-http-request-upload.ts'
 @ ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js 51:32-68
 @ ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/index.js 11:9-38
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/http-connection/dist/esm/index.js 2:0-46 4:47-61
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/web3-provider/dist/esm/index.js 3:0-60 338:22-36
 @ ./src/App.js 7:0-65 18:24-45
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 11:33-36

WARNING in ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\xml-http-request.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\xml-http-request.ts'
 @ ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/index.js 11:9-38
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/http-connection/dist/esm/index.js 2:0-46 4:47-61
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/web3-provider/dist/esm/index.js 3:0-60 338:22-36
 @ ./src/App.js 7:0-65 18:24-45
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 11:33-36

WARNING in src\App.js
  Line 1:8:  'logo' is defined but never used   no-unused-vars
  Line 3:8:  'react' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

109 warnings have detailed information that is not shown.
Use 'stats.errorDetails: true' resp. '--stats-error-details' to show it.


ERROR in ./node_modules/ethereumjs-abi/node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist/object.js 8:13-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'assert' in 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\ethereumjs-abi\node_modules\ethereumjs-util\dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "assert": require.resolve("assert/") }'
        - install 'assert'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "assert": false }
 @ ./node_modules/ethereumjs-abi/node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist/index.js 73:13-32
 @ ./node_modules/ethereumjs-abi/lib/index.js 2:14-40
 @ ./node_modules/ethereumjs-abi/index.js 1:0-42
 @ ./node_modules/eth-sig-util/index.js 3:15-40
 @ ./node_modules/web3-provider-engine/subproviders/hooked-wallet.js 16:16-39
 @ ./node_modules/@walletconnect/web3-provider/dist/esm/index.js 14:32-90
 @ ./src/App.js 7:0-65 18:24-45
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 11:33-36


19 errors have detailed information that is not shown.
Use 'stats.errorDetails: true' resp. '--stats-error-details' to show it.

webpack 5.68.0 compiled with 19 errors and 110 warnings in 23859 ms
```

And this is part of the error message as it appears in the web page:

```
Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./node_modules/cipher-base/index.js 3:16-43

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\cipher-base'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/eth-lib/lib/bytes.js 9:193-227

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\eth-lib\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/node_modules/eth-lib/lib/bytes.js 7:193-227

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\web3-eth-accounts\node_modules\eth-lib\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js 37:11-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
    - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "http": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js 39:12-28

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "https": require.resolve("https-browserify") }'
    - install 'https-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "https": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js 41:9-22

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'
    - install 'os-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "os": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js 43:10-24

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in 'F:\Work\Tellor\testField\test-wallet-connect\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/") }'
    - install 'url'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "url": false }
```

I tried to install the missing libraries in the second error message but it didn't work!

Answer (score 9):

You can run those commands:

```
yarn remove react-scripts

yarn add react-scripts@4.0.3
```

Comment: this answer needs more explanation. is that bug on react-scripts@5 or intentional behavior?

Comment: had a similar error and this worked, thanks!

Comment: Not really ideal solution, cause this would downgrade react scripts from latest version 5.0.0.

Comment: Any resolution for React 18? I'm 5.0.0 version as well and downgrading doesn't seem to be the right way to achieve it

Answer (score 7):

This is the issue: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11756#issuecomment-1001130053

The problem is webpack v5 made breaking changes that means that  WalletConnectProvider: '@walletconnect/web3-provider' package needs to be updated to work with the updated webpackv5 and react-scripts.

Instead of downgrading scripts - the best thing is for walletConnect (or an awesome community member with know-how) to update this issue.

Since that could take awhile, you can alternatively use react-app-rewired to polyfill it (I make no guarantees on performance and this isn't really an ideal solution either - you're basically ejecting your app), but it's a stop-gap.

Install react-app-rewired.
 `npm install react-app-rewired`

Create new file config-overrides.js in your root directory
`touch config-overrides.js`

Put this in the file

```
/* config-overrides.js */
const webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  //do stuff with the webpack config...

  config.resolve.fallback = {
    url: require.resolve('url'),
    assert: require.resolve('assert'),
    crypto: require.resolve('crypto-browserify'),
    http: require.resolve('stream-http'),
    https: require.resolve('https-browserify'),
    os: require.resolve('os-browserify/browser'),
    buffer: require.resolve('buffer'),
    stream: require.resolve('stream-browserify')
  };
  config.plugins.push(
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      process: 'process/browser',
      Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer']
    })
  );

  return config;
};
```

Change your scripts to use react-app-rewired with react in package.json

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "react-app-rewired start",
   "build": "react-app-rewired build",
   "test": "react-app-rewired test",
   "eject": "react-app-rewired eject"
 },
```

You may need to install process & browserify as dev-dependencies:
`npm install --save-dev process browserify`

Comment: Looking at walletconnect modules it seems they distribute the files along with the sourcemaps, can you elaborate what walletconnect should change?

Answer (score 2):

The latest React version uses webpack v5 in its react-scripts which is not working so well at the moment with Wallet Connect/Web3 Provider. I recommend using 4.0.3 because it is using webpack 4 which is stable and currently used by the Ethereum Boilerplate. So the answer above is the right thing to do

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade `react-scripts` but if you're also using updated `react-dom` and `react` i.e `v18`, a full downgrade works.

You can run those commands:

```
yarn remove react-scripts react react-dom

yarn add react-scripts@4.0.3 react-dom@17.0.0 react@17.0.0
```

OR

```
npm uninstall react-scripts react react-dom

npm install react-scripts@4.0.3 react-dom@17.0.0 react@17.0.0
```

Also check your `index.js` to update your `React-dom` implementation to fit the version.

P.S: If you're using `Chakra` which was my case also run

```
yarn remove framer-motion

yarn add framer-motion@4.1.17
```

Answer (score 0):

As Ally said you will require to install react-app-rewired and source-map-loader.

```
npm i -D react-app-rewired
npm i -D source-map-loader
```

Create the config-overrides.js file at the root of your project.
And add the Solana team's basic example of config-overrides.js file - https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/blob/master/packages/starter/create-react-app-starter/config-overrides.js

Change the package.json file scripts section

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-app-rewired eject"
  },
```

It works with the latest packages.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

1. Install the "react-app-rewired".

```
yarn add react-app-rewired
```

2. Add the "config-overrides.js" file in the root directory. The code resource is from the official project.

```
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = function override(config) {
  const fallback = config.resolve.fallback || {};
  config.resolve.fallback = fallback;
  config.plugins = (config.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      process: "process/browser",
      Buffer: ["buffer", "Buffer"],
    }),
  ]);
  config.resolve.extensions.push(".mjs");
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.m?js/,
    resolve: {
      fullySpecified: false,
    },
  });

  return {
    ...config,
    // This is needed to not show the warning about this modules don't have src files, only on dist (build)
    ignoreWarnings: [
      {
        module: /node_modules\/@walletconnect/,
      },
      {
        module: /node_modules\/eth-rpc-errors/,
      },
      {
        module: /node_modules\/json-rpc-engine/,
      },
      {
        module: /node_modules\/@metamask/,
      },
      {
        module: /node_modules\/@gnosis.pm/,
      },
    ],
  };
};
```

3. Modify the "scripts" section in the package.json as below:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build"
  },
```